# Função mouseout em ícone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que ao passar o mouse em cima do icone de pesquisa fosse carregado um campo input.

html

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse pull-right">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="contato"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
      </ul>

</div> <!-- /#navbar -->
```

Comment: Posta a estrutura do menu em `HTML` que tem aí.

Comment: Desculpe, nao vi que tinha ficado sem o HTML.

Comment: Que erro estás a ter? Que código tentaste e nao funcionou? Estás a usar alguma ferramenta?

Comment: @MoshMage, não estava utilizando nem um codigo, pois não sabia como fazer. Tentei pesquisar na net mas não achei nada.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar adicionar um "ouvinte" para o evento do tipo `mouseover`, ao ouvir esse evento, você adiciona um `input` onde deseja. Da mesma forma, deve remover o `input`quando usuário tirar o mouse do input, ouvindo um evento do tipo `mouseout`.
Vou dar um exemplo onde ao tirar o mouse o input não sai, mas sim, quando o usuário tirar o foco do input.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#contato").on("mouseover", function() {
    $(this).parent().prepend("<input class='form-control input-lg' type='text' placeholder='Pesquisar..'/>");
    $(this).parent().find("input").focus().on("blur", function() {
      $(this).remove();
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><a href="contato" id="contato"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Faça um teste passando o mouse em cima do ícone depois clicando fora para perder o foco do input.

Os pormenores vai depender de você agora.

Alternativamente, você pode utilizar o plugin [ExpadingSearchBar](https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ExpandingSearchBar/).

Comment: Vou estudar o codigo que você me passou e também vo dar um olhda no plugin que sugeriste.